# Why do my run level directories contain only start scripts and no single kill script?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, etc, runlevel

I learned here that for each runlevel exist a directory with start and kill scripts. The start scripts are activated on entering , the kill scripts on leaving the runlevel. Start scripts and kill scripts for each level are contained within /etc/rcX.d (X stands for the runlevel).

But, when I made a total listing of all runlevel directories for runlevels 2 till 5 (0 is for halt and 6 for reboot) by entering "ls /etc/rc{2..5}.d, I got the following listing:

[image]

As you see, all files starts with a S, as for the naming conventions they should be all start scripts - not a single file starting with K (kill script) is contained.

I am confused by this, why are there no kill scripts contained as expected ?

Comment: may be better served on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

I notice these **are all identical**, meaning there are, e.g., no services running in level 3 that aren't running in 4, etc.  So nothing needs to be shut down moving from one to the next.

If you try `update-rc.d` (I'm not a Mint user, but I'm presuming it's Debian derived and still uses this stuff) on some particular service so that it is only on in one particular level, `K` scripts for it will appear in the other levels.

The shutdown kills are all in `rc6.d`, of course.  Note there's probably also an `rcS.d` if it follows Debian's (slightly sneaky) model -- I *think* they introduced that.